# Excel vba sum formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I tried to add formula to one of the cell with VBA as below:

```
With Selection
       .Merge
       .Offset(0, 2).Resize(2, 4).Merge
       .Offset(0, 7).Resize(2, 5).Merge
       .Offset(0, 7).Formula = "=R[0]C[-5]/SUM(EB:EB)"
       .Offset(0, 7).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
End With
```

but when i check the cell, the formula is displayed as `=EB16/SUM(EB:(EB))`

what did i do wrong with the formula? thanks.

Comment: you included actual column references with `R1C1` notation which will not work. Change `SUM(EB:EB)` to whatever column reference away is the correct number. Something like `SUM(10:10)` where 10 is the distance away from the cell with the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix and mash together xlR1C1 and xlA1 cell addresses.

```
With Selection
       .Merge
       .Offset(0, 2).Resize(2, 4).Merge
       .Offset(0, 7).Resize(2, 5).Merge
       .Offset(0, 7).Formula = "=" & .offset(0, 2).address(0, 0) & "/SUM(EB:EB)"
       .Offset(0, 7).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
End With
```

It's a little hard to determine the exact cell reference but RC[-5] should be Offset(0, 2) when placed into a cell Offset(0, 7) from the original selection.

Comment: yup, it is working now. didn't realise the mixing of the R1C1 and xlA1 is invalid. another solution using R1C1: `.Offset(0, 7).Formula = "=R[0]C[-5]/SUM(c[-5])"`